# Multi line Reg Exp match

Tags: regex

As an example take this chunk:

> The cat sat on the
>   mat, and the dog
>   could not get his place in
>
> front of the fire.

I have an expression to match a string between two strings, and return just the contents between:

```
put "(?<=\The cat)(.*)(?=\the)" into myreg
```

returns: cat sat on

How can i expand this to match across multiple lines..?
To obtain this from the code:

```
put "(?<=\The cat)(.*)(?=\fire)" into myreg
```

so i want:

cat sat on the
mat, and the dog
could not get his place in 
front of the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` in a regex will match anything except a new line. There is a modifier (the specific on depends on the platform) to make it multiline. It typically is one of `s`, `m` or `n`.

Alternatively, replace (.*) with something like:

```
((?:.|\s)*)
```

Comment: Or use `[\s\S]` to match _any_ char.

Comment: Thanks Denis, I am working with the live code platform, to deploy on OSX. if i was to use the m modifier, where would i put that..? i tried: "(?<=\The cat)(.*)(?=\fire)/m" and "(?<=\The cat)(.*/m)(?=\fire)" without joy.

Comment: In php it would look like `/regex/s`. Not sure for Obj-C. But as suggested by Bart, try: `(?<=\The cat)([\s\S]*)(?=\fire)`.

Comment: I have another problem with that. It is to greedy and in the real working example, i am matching between the strings: "<key>" and "</array>". There are lots of instances of </array> in the document, it matches everything between "<key>" and the last instance of "</array>". I just want it to look for the next instance of "</array" after it finds "<key>".

Comment: You can make operators non-greedy by trailing them with a `?`: `([\s\S]*?)`. And you should *not* be [parsing html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) using regex.

Comment: Hmm.. that post in the link is pretty explicit :-) .. Your last example actually works a treat in my static test. I was planning on pulling the file into a var and running the regex, and writing the file back. Can you give me an example why that may fail..?

Comment: If you've nested keys, it'll go bonkers. `<array> <key>foo</key> <val> <array><key>bar</key><val>baz</val></array> </val> </array>`

Comment: Doesn't Ojb-C have a plist parser/reader that you can use as is?

Comment: Any way, this answer to my original question is good, and marked as answered. appreciated.

Comment: I will look into the plist parser, and see if live code has an api for that. Nested keys are not likely in this particular file. I have modified the file in as many ways as i can think of from within osx, and it always comes out with the same format. This way seems real easy, now i have the regex, but i will look for a more solid alternative. I do also have the luxury of expanding that regex a little to narrow down the chance of failure: "(?<=\<key>AccountURL</key>)((?:.|\s)*?)(?=\</array>)".